# Where to find nice foreign language fonts

Tags: fonts, inspiration

I have encountered a few nicely designed foreign language fonts like for Devanagari, but doing a search for "beautiful foreign language typography designs" doesn't bring up anything. I know about Google Noto which is very nice, but I'm wondering if there's anything else out there, any other good resources.

Comment: I think "foreign" is not applicable to fonts. If you are referring to alphabet types maybe you should rectify your question to [Latin Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet) or [not Latin Alphabet](https://sites.google.com/site/worldfactsinc/Non-Latin-Script-Languages-Of-The-World), or specify what type of alphabet you are looking for: Greek, Cyrillic, Hebrew, Chinese, Arabic ... German people speaks german language and they use the same latin alphabet. Many of the people on this site are foreigners among themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search fonts for different writing systems. For ex. Devanagari is the native writing system for popular Indian and Himalayan languages.  Learn at first something about writing systems and then search fonts for them. Start from this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_writing_systems

BTW. Beautiful is an opinion which depend on context, tradition and personal attitude. What's beautiful for you, others cannot decide it.